# Top 1 on unique event

Tags: sql-server-2008

The table name is Events

```
name    event_id    qty
n1      1           8
n1      2           9
n2      2           25
n3      2           29
n4      2           10
n4      3           11
n3      3           57
n2      3           1
n5      3           2
n1      3           90
```

i want only to select top 1 for distinct event_id. What is the sql query for it? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY event_id)
             FROM Events)
SELECT name,event_id,qty FROM CTE WHERE RN=1
```

Result:

```
NAME    EVENT_ID    QTY
n1      1           8
n1      2           9  
n4      3           11
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ace83/1).

**EDIT:**

For descending order of qty:

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT *,RN=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY event_id ORDER BY event_id)
FROM Events)
SELECT name,event_id,qty FROM CTE WHERE RN=1 ORDER BY QTY DESC
```

Result:

```
NAME    EVENT_ID    QTY
n4      3           11
n1      2           9
n1      1           8
```

Comment: @damdeok: See the edit in my answer. Feel free to accept the answer if you are satisfied.

Comment: @RagingBull - yes. I think he did not express the question clearly. For the record, my query as a comment - `select top 1 event_id, COUNT(qty) as tqty
from Events
group by event_id
order by tqty desc` It should have been `select top 1 for distinct combination of name and event_id` instead of just event_id.

Comment: thanks raging bull, i just edited your code with this "ORDER BY qty desc". yes, i haven't clearly stated what i want.

Comment: @RagingBull, event_id will grow and I want to limit it. So in the example above, how can I show only 2 event_id ordered asc?

Comment: @damdeok: Replace `SELECT name,event,...` with `SELECT TOP 2 name,event,...`.